# Boost asio socket connection through proxy server

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, proxy, boost-asio

I have a client / server setup to communicate with each other using boost's asio sockets.  The protocol is trivial, it starts with a 64-bit value telling how long the following data is and the rest comes in as JSON.

Problem is, it doesn't support a proxy between client and server and now we need to support that.

As I've read online, it looks like proxies in general are very simple.  For an HTTP proxy you contact the proxy and give it a CONNECT request for the actual URL you want and it just passes things on.

But I haven't understood how to reconcile that with my non-HTTP data.

1. Will I need to change my "protocol" to have it work with proxy
   servers?  I see this suggested:

   `CONNECT http://my.server.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`

   but how to do with my non-protocol?
2. I have tried that telling it I'm using HTTP and then sending the
   JSON data next but have run into a series of problems with it, to
   the point where I don't know if the problem is just my
   implementation or if what I'm trying to do simply won't work.
3. If I'm completely off base here, I'd love to be straightened out.

Comment: seems easiest to me if you write a third daemon, one that speaks your protocol and acts as a client and server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think piggybacking on an HTTP proxy is the correct solution here. Right now you have

```
Client <---------> Server
```

But you want

```
Client <------> proxy <------> Server
```

I'd suggest writing the proxy yourself. It will be a daemon just like your server, and should speak both your client and server protocol. The protocol will likely have to be amended so the proxy knows the server address and service. Likewise the client will need additional information to connect to the proxy rather than the server.

Comment: I suspect your suggestion answers things for me.  Which is, for corporate reasons, that won't work.  But since I haven't had anyone explain to me how to make my setup work, I fear that means there's no simple and clean solution, which means I need to rewrite things to speak HTTP.

Comment: @user2073267 What are the *corporate reasons*?

Comment: Telling customers that they have to run our proxy server.  So instead of our app just working, we'd be telling them that they'd have to install our proxy, too.  That's especially a no-go given that the places they use a proxy server for themselves are the places they're most concerned about security, so they're unlikely to want to run our new proxy server.

Comment: @user2073267 you should edit your question with these restrictions